# Update data in textboxfor fields using a selected object in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a view where my user can create a new item, he will have to select an item from a dropdownlist like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.m_CustomerId, ViewBag.ListCustomers as SelectList, "--- Select Customer ---", new  {@class = "CustomerInfo" })
```

When the selection is made, there are fields in the current view that would name to be updated with the selection made. Those fields are like those:

```
Item Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.m_ItemName, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_ItemName)<br/>
        Item Date: <span style="font-weight: bold">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_ItemDate)</span> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_ItemDate)<br/>
```

I've read a few things like maybe using JQuery or Java, but I'm honestly cluesless and I don't know these languages. How could I do this? I do not mind trying out languages, scripts or anything else, but I'm rather a newbie in MVC app and this is puzzling me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that I don't mind trying out or working around with any languages

Comment: That would be jQuery or *javascript*, not *java*.

Comment: Oh, and you really need to learn javascript.  It is essential if you doing web development.  [Here's](http://jqfundamentals.com/) a decent resource to get you going.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the tutorial @Forty-Two, you are right. I will plunder this site very soon!

Answer (score 1):

So what you might want to do is download and install jQuery via NuGet Package Manager. Once you've gotten that installed then we can extend the controls. You could extend the `DropDownListFor` by adding some attributes.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.m_CustomerId,
    ViewBag.ListCustomers as SelectList,
    "--- Select Customer ---",
    new
    {
        @class = "CustomerInfo",
        onchange = "function() { $('m_ItemName').val($(this).text()); }"
    }
)
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that model is your server side object and selection in the dropdown happens on the front end.  Model values are rendered on page load.  If you need to do anything more complicated than displaying selected drop down value (like Model.CustomerName and Model.CustomerPhone) you will either need to create javascript object to hold complete list of customers or have another server call to load customer properties based on selected value.

Comment: Oh. I see. So that is more complicated that I want. @smvlad I do not mind trying those out. In theory, the dropdownlistfor is holding those values.
I'm wondering if it would not be easier to figure out with a partial view?